# Giving maven dependency error in Spark 2.3

Tags: apache-spark

I am building spark 2.3 scala code using maven , giving following error.

> error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file SparkSession.class.

This is snippet of pom file, please advise

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How do you do "I am building spark 2.3 scala code using maven"? Could you describe the steps exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your Java and Scala versions. They should be 1.6 or higher and 2.11 respectively. Or it could also be a mismatch with other dependencies like spark_sql.Make sure you have same version across all dependencies.